# Proof of bound for Lovasz Local lemma

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove, using a probabilistic argument, that the list coloring number of a bipartite graph of degree at most $d$ is $O\left(\frac{d}{log(d)}\right)$.

For this, I have built a Lovasz graph and in order be able to apply the Lovasz local lemma I need to show that
$$ e (d^2-d+1) \left[1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)^d\right]^t \leq 1$$

if $t = O\left(\frac{d}{log(d)}\right)$

I've been trying to work out the math for a while now but so far it hasn't taken me anywhere. Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $t=\frac{kd}{\log{d}}$ and we have

$$
\begin{align*}
e(d^2-d+1)\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)^d\right)^t &= e^{\log(d^2-d+1)+1}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}}\right)^d\right)^{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}}\\
&= e^{\log(d^2-d+1)+1}\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}}\right)^{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}\cdot\frac{\log{d}}{k}}\right)^{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}}\\
&\approx e^{\log(d^2-d+1)+1}\left(1-e^{-\frac{\log{d}}{k}}\right)^{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}}\\
&= e^{\log(d^2-d+1)+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{d^{\frac{1}{k}}}\right)^{\frac{kd}{\log{d}}}\\  
&= e^{\log(d^2-d+1)+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{d^{\frac{1}{k}}}\right)^{d^{\frac{1}{k}}\cdot \frac{kd^{(k-1)/k}}{\log{d}}}\\ 
&\approx e^{\log(d^2-d+1)+1}e^{\frac{-kd}{\log{d}}}\\
\end{align*}
$$
For $k$ sufficiently large.

Then we want the exponent to be less than $0$ in order for the entire expression to be smaller than $1$. That means
$$
\log{d}(\log(d^2-d+1)+1)-kd\le0\iff k\ge\frac{\log{d}(\log(d^2-d+1)+1)}{d}.
$$
Now
$$
\frac{\log{d}(\log(d^2-d+1)+1)}{d}\le\frac{\log{d}(\log(d^2)+1)}{d}\le\frac{2(\log{d})^2}{d}+\frac{1}{e}=f(d)
$$
and $f(d)$ attains a maximum at $d=e^2$ so that $f(e^2)=\frac{8}{e^2}+\frac 1e\le 1.46.$ Thus for $k$ sufficiently large, our claim holds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Laars!
I think that if we make $t = kd/log(d)$ and do a similar process, we might be able to get the expression to be less than 1 for $d\geq 0$ and some value of $k$.
After all, I need to prove the bound for $t = O(d/log(d))$ so we might as well take advantage of the constants.
I'll try give it a try :)

Comment: Ah! I forgot about the constant. I intentionally left it out to simplify the manipulations. I am going to see if I can fix it and edit my answer.

Comment: There I think I fixed it. Ana, let me know if you agree when you have a chance.

Comment: Perfect, I also did the calculations as well and got the same result. I did some looser bounds which made $k$ bigger but in the end got the proof.
Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like $1.32588<k<1.32589$ by playing with the function in a graphing calculator, but who cares, right? :)